# Convert array of objects into HTML markup of a table

Tags: javascript, html

i have following array

```
[
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'address', results: 'address', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'bansal', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 3 },
  {
    label: 'Last Name*',
    results: 'sss.ca',
    sequence: 4,
    entry_id: 3
  },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 3 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 3 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 3 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 4 },
  {
    label: 'Last Name*',
    results: 'ssss.ca',
    sequence: 4,
    entry_id: 4
  },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 4 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 4 },
  { label: 'address', results: 'add', sequence: 5, entry_id: 4 }
]
```

i need to convert into HTML Table

```
> <table><tr><th>Untitled</th><th>Last
> Name*</th><th>Category</th><th>address</th></tr>
> 
> <tr><td>1234</td><td>ggg</td><td>test</td><td></td></tr> .... ... so
> on  </table>
```

Can anybody tell me how to make an array to simplify this so i can create a table ? do we need multidimensional array. i need final html string. any trick please

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov all the answers are not correct

Comment: At least 2 of provided answers are followed with live-demo which proves that those **ARE** correct. Considering they didn't fit your expectations, I guess the problem is that your input data is somewhat inconsistent with sample HTML, which makes me think that it is rather problem statement and lack of focus is the issue here.

Comment: @Problem is that they didnt read the question carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of solution using JS:

```js
var html_code = "<table><tr><th>label</th><th>results</th><th>sequence</th><th>entry_id</th></tr>";
var arr= [
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'address', results: 'address', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'bansal', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 2 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 3 },
  {
    label: 'Last Name*',
    results: 'sss.ca',
    sequence: 4,
    entry_id: 3
  },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 3 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 3 },
  { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 3 },
  { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 4 },
  {
    label: 'Last Name*',
    results: 'ssss.ca',
    sequence: 4,
    entry_id: 4
  },
  { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 4 },
  { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 4 },
  { label: 'address', results: 'add', sequence: 5, entry_id: 4 }
];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
   html_code+="<tr><td>"+ arr[i].label  +"</td><td>"+ arr[i].results  +"</td><td>"+ arr[i].sequence  +"</td><td>"+ arr[i].entry_id  +"</td></tr>";
}
html_code+="</table>";

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = html_code;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: No label value must be need to show in TH. this is not required

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this JQuery Code.

```
 //HTML code
<div id="here_table"></div>

//Script
var arr= [
    { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'address', results: 'address', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'bansal', sequence: 4, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 1 },
    { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 2 },
    { label: 'Last Name*', results: 'ggg', sequence: 4, entry_id: 2 },
    { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 2 },
    { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 2 },
    { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 2 },
    { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 3 },
    {
        label: 'Last Name*',
        results: 'sss.ca',
        sequence: 4,
        entry_id: 3
    },
    { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 3 },
    { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 3 },
    { label: 'address', results: '', sequence: 5, entry_id: 3 },
    { label: 'Untitled', results: '1234', sequence: 2, entry_id: 4 },
    {
        label: 'Last Name*',
        results: 'ssss.ca',
        sequence: 4,
        entry_id: 4
    },
    { label: 'Country', results: 'India', sequence: 3, entry_id: 4 },
    { label: 'Category', results: 'test', sequence: 6, entry_id: 4 },
    { label: 'address', results: 'add', sequence: 5, entry_id: 4 }
];


var content = "<table>"
arr.forEach(function(singleRecord) {
    content += '<tr><td>' + singleRecord.label + '</td><td>' + singleRecord.results + '</td><td>' + singleRecord.sequence + '</td></tr>';
});

content += "</table>"

$('#here_table').append(content);
```